# yanking lines from a buffer that isn't the active one

Tags: vim

Let's say there are two loaded buffers/files and they are both displayed via split windows, line numbers are enabled and thus known.

Is there a way to stay in one buffer, specify a line of the other buffer and yank it so it can be put into the active buffer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
:let @0 = join(getbufline('#', 42), "\n") . "\n"
```

(Replace `#` with the name of the other buffer and `42` with the line number within the other buffer.)

Comment: Nice, I didn't know about `getbufline()`. To yank and insert in one step, you could use this `:put=getbufline('#', 42)`.

Answer (score 3):

If both buffers have been saved to disk, and you have *sed* available on your system you can use this.

```
:r !sed -n -e 42p #
```

Replace 42 with the line you want copied from the alternate buffer.

This command will `:read` the output from `!sed` (the *sed* program), which has been instructed to only (`-n`) print `p` line `42` from the "other" `#` file. The contents are inserted below the current line in the current (`%`) buffer.

Answer (score 1):

are you comparing/editing similar files? Perhaps

```
:vert diffsplit otherfilename
```

or (if the bufferes were open already)

```
:windo diffthis
```

Would be reasonable. In diffmode, there are commands

```
:diffput
:diffget
```

and their normal command equivalents (<kbd>d</kbd><kbd>p</kbd>, <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>o</kbd> (_obtain)) to grab and insert/replace lines from the other buffer.